# TypeScript: Can I declare that an interface may have any number of further attributes?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to express "instances of this interface have a number called 'num', a function called 'func' and may have any number of more attribute with unspecified name that are of type string" in TypeScript? **I imagine** it might look like this:

```typescript
interface MyInterface {
  num: number;
  func: Function;
  *: string;
}
```

You probably want to tell me that this is poor API-Design, but I am writing definition files for a 3rd party library and I cannot change that :-(.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest syntax is as follows:

```
interface MyInterface {
    [index: string]: any;
    num: number;
    func: Function;
}

var a: MyInterface = {
    num: 123,
    func: function () {},
    prop1: 'Hello',
    prop2: 'World'
};
```

The type "any" must be used because the properties "num" and "func" are not strings:

> While index signatures are a powerful way to describe the array and
>   'dictionary' pattern, they also enforce that all properties match
>   their return type.

Source: the [TS Handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#interfaces-array-types).

Answer (score 0):

I think if you just want an object that isn't strongly typed, you should declare your class as type "any"

```
declare var MyObject:any;
```

If your interface isn't really related to something concrete and won't have a structured set of properties and methods, then why force it to be an interface at all? The compiled JS won't make much sense, but it should compile for you.

Comment: I want to force for several reasons: 1. documentation (this also includes code completion for the type in my IDE) 2. I can still check the existing types...

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are open, so if you want to extend one, you can - your extension must be in the same common root (i.e. the same "namespace" location if you are used to thinking in namespaces):

```
interface MyInterface {
    num: number;
    func: Function;
}

//...

interface MyInterface {
    additional: string;
    somethingElse: number;
}
```

When you use `MyInterface` you'll see all members, for example at this location:

```
function example(input: MyInterface) {
    input.      
}
```

You will see `num, func, additional, somethingElse` in the auto-completion list.

## Update

If you genuinely want arbitrary string-keyed values (you won't get auto-completion or type checking for these) you can access them by key. All of the non-arbitrary properties and methods will still get auto-completion and type checking:

```
var x: MyInterface = {
    num: 1,
    func: () => 2
};

x['ArbitraryString'] = 'Arbitrary value';

alert(x['ArbitraryString']);
```

Comment: I've learned something that might come in handy at time. But I fear that it does not answer my question. This still does not allow me to specify that arbitrary further attributes of type string might exist.

Comment: @yankee you would have to specify them on the interface to get all the TypeScript goodness, but you can just use the keys (as per my update) to add anything you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array interface syntax as mentioned by a few of the other answers:

```
interface MyInterface {
    [index: string]: any;
    MyString: string;
    someFunc: () => void;
}

var myInstance: MyInterface = {
    MyString: 'Hello',
    someFunc: () => {},
    SomeOtherProp: 'Another'
};
```

Sadly, you will get a compiler error if you try to access one of the arbitrary properties directly:

```
var y = myInstance.SomeOtherProp;
```

But, you can get around this by using an interface without the indexer:

```
interface MyInterface {
    MyString: string;
    someFunc: () => void;
}

var myInstance: MyInterface = {
    MyString: 'Hello',
    someFunc: () => {},
    SomeOtherProp: 'Another'
};
```

And then casting your object to :

```
var y = (<any>myInstance).SomeOtherProp;
```

This will give you intellisense for the arbitrary property and also compiles out to the semantic javascript that you would expect:

```
var y = myInstance.SomeOtherProp;
```

This does *not* allow declaring that you intend to have an arbitrary list of string properties that can be added to you object, but as far as I can tell, there is no way to do this in TypeScript as of now.